# Div drop-down menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to design a drop-down menu using div and jQuery.

**Expected Results**

- On Clicking the Parent(Root) menu, the drop-down menu shows.
- On hover of the drop-down menu, if the drop-down menu has child menus, it shows.
- If a clicks away from the menu area, opened drop-down menu hides

[The fiddle I have created can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/1jhy0c54)

```
<div class="sc-bdVaJa dHnqvJ">
  <div class="drop-down">
    <div class="drop-down__label">Help</div>
    <div class="sc-bdVaJa dHnqvJ">
      <div class="drop-down__menu">
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">1. Online Manual</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">2. Contents &amp; Index</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">3. Keyboard Shortcuts</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">4. About...</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">5. Downloads</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow"></div>
          <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="sc-bdVaJa fSbntV">
              <div class="drop-down__menu">
                <div class="drop-down__row">
                  <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                  <div class="drop-down__text">1. API Doc</div>
                  <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                  <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="drop-down__row--disable">
                  <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                  <div class="drop-down__text">2. FAQ (PDF)</div>
                  <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                  <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="drop-down__row">
                            <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                            <div class="drop-down__text">3. Press Release Docs</div>
            <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                            <div class="drop-down__arrow"></div>
                            <div style="position: relative;">
                                <div class="sc-bdVaJa fSbntV">
                                    <div class="drop-down__menu">
                                        <div class="drop-down__row">
                                            <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                                            <div class="drop-down__text">1. First Qtr </div>
                    <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                                            <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="drop-down__row--disable">
                                            <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                                            <div class="drop-down__text">2.  Second Qtr </div>
                    <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                                            <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="drop-down__row">
                                            <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                                            <div class="drop-down__text">3.  Third Qtr </div>
                    <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                                            <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">6. Live Chat</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can jquery event like `hover`,`mouseleave`etc to hide and show your menu on hover and hide it when mouse leave that element .Also i have added click event to hide the menu if click outside `menu`.Working code :

```js
$('.drop-down').on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('.drop-down__menu').css({
    display: "grid"
  });
  $(this).find('.drop-down__row .fSbntV').css({
    display: "none"
  });
});
//if menu is hover
$('.drop-down').hover(function() {
//showing menus
  $(this).find('.drop-down__menu').css({
    display: "grid"
  }).show();
  $(this).find('.drop-down__row .fSbntV').css({
    display: "none"
  });
//if download class is hover
  $('.download').hover(function() {
    $('.drop-down__row .fSbntV').css({
      display: "block"
    }).show();
  });


});
//if click outside menu hide it
$(document).click(function(event) {
  $('.drop-down__menu').css({
    display: "none"
  });

});

//if not hovered outside menu hide it
$("div.drop-down .dHnqvJ").on("mouseleave",function(e) {
  $('.drop-down__menu').css({
    display: "none"
  });
   e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

```css
.dHnqvJ {
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  right: initial;
  bottom: initial;
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row {
  position: relative;
  display: contents;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row:hover>*:not(:nth-child(5)) {
  background: #e99f17;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row:hover>.drop-down__check>.drop-down__icon {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--active {
  position: relative;
  display: contents;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--active>.drop-down__check>.drop-down__icon {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--active>*:not(:nth-child(5)) {
  background: #e99f17;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--disable {
  display: contents;
  color: #8c8c8cb5;
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--disable:hover>* {
  background: #e99f17;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__title {
  padding: 0 7px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1660e8;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgb(100, 100, 100);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  grid-template-columns: 16px auto auto 15px 0px;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__separator {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  height: 7px;
  padding: 3px 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__check {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__icon {
  max-width: 13px;
  max-height: 13px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2px);
  transform: translateX(-2px);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 8px;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__hot-key {
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-column: 3;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__arrow {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__arrow:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__arrow--disable {
  grid-column: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sc-bdVaJa dHnqvJ">
  <div class="drop-down">
    <div class="drop-down__label">Help</div>
    <div class="sc-bdVaJa dHnqvJ">
      <div class="drop-down__menu">
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">1. Online Manual</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">2. Contents &amp; Index</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">3. Keyboard Shortcuts</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">4. About...</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text download">5. Downloads</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow"></div>
          <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="sc-bdVaJa fSbntV">
              <div class="drop-down__menu">
                <div class="drop-down__row">
                  <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                  <div class="drop-down__text">1. API Doc</div>
                  <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                  <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="drop-down__row--disable">
                  <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                  <div class="drop-down__text">2. FAQ (PDF)</div>
                  <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                  <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="drop-down__row">
                  <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                  <div class="drop-down__text">3. Press Release Docs</div>
                  <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                  <div class="drop-down__arrow"></div>
                  <div style="position: relative;">
                    <div class="sc-bdVaJa fSbntV">
                      <div class="drop-down__menu">
                        <div class="drop-down__row">
                          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                          <div class="drop-down__text">1. First Qtr </div>
                          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="drop-down__row--disable">
                          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                          <div class="drop-down__text">2. Second Qtr </div>
                          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="drop-down__row">
                          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                          <div class="drop-down__text">3. Third Qtr </div>
                          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down__row">
          <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
          <div class="drop-down__text">6. Live Chat</div>
          <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
          <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't click on the menu as i move mouse the drop down disappear

Comment: @AbdulhaqShah thank you for pointing out . I have corrected it .

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it like this with click.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".drop-down");

  //check if the clicked area is dropDown or not
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.drop-down__menu').hide();
  }
});

/* $('div.submenu').hide(); */
$('.drop-down__arrow').hover(function() {
  debugger
  if ($('.submenu', this).length > 0) {
    $(this).find('.submenu').css({
      display: "grid"
    });
  }
}, function() {
  if ($('.submenu', this).length > 0) {
    $('.submenu').hide();
  }
});


$('.drop-down').on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('.drop-down__menu').css({
    display: "grid"
  });
  $(this).find('.drop-down__row .fSbntV').css({
    display: "none"
  });
});
```

```css
.dHnqvJ {
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  right: initial;
  bottom: initial;
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row {
  position: relative;
  display: contents;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row:hover>*:not(:nth-child(5)) {
  background: #e99f17;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row:hover>.drop-down__check>.drop-down__icon {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--active {
  position: relative;
  display: contents;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--active>.drop-down__check>.drop-down__icon {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--active>*:not(:nth-child(5)) {
  background: #e99f17;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--disable {
  display: contents;
  color: #8c8c8cb5;
  cursor: not-allowed
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__row--disable:hover>* {
  background: #e99f17;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__title {
  padding: 0 7px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1660e8;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgb(100, 100, 100);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  grid-template-columns: 16px auto auto 15px 0px;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__separator {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  height: 7px;
  padding: 3px 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__check {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__icon {
  max-width: 13px;
  max-height: 13px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2px);
  transform: translateX(-2px);
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 8px;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__hot-key {
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-column: 3;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__arrow {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__arrow:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.dHnqvJ .drop-down__arrow--disable {
  grid-column: 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Drop-down Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sc-bdVaJa dHnqvJ">
      <div class="drop-down">
        <div class="drop-down__label">Help</div>
        <div class="sc-bdVaJa dHnqvJ">
          <div class="drop-down__menu">
            <div class="drop-down__row">
              <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
              <div class="drop-down__text">1. Online Manual</div>
              <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
              <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-down__row">
              <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
              <div class="drop-down__text">2. Contents &amp; Index</div>
              <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
              <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-down__row">
              <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
              <div class="drop-down__text">3. Keyboard Shortcuts</div>
              <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
              <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-down__row">
              <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
              <div class="drop-down__text">4. About...</div>
              <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
              <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-down__row">
              <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
              <div class="drop-down__text">5. Downloads</div>
              <span class="drop-down__hot-key "></span>
              <div class="drop-down__arrow">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                  <div class="sc-bdVaJa fSbntV submenu">
                    <div class="drop-down__menu">
                      <div class="drop-down__row">
                        <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                        <div class="drop-down__text">1. API Doc</div>
                        <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                        <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="drop-down__row--disable">
                        <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                        <div class="drop-down__text">2. FAQ (PDF)</div>
                        <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                        <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="drop-down__row">
                        <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                        <div class="drop-down__text">3. Press Release Docs</div>
                        <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                        <div class="drop-down__arrow"></div>
                        <div style="position: relative;">
                          <div class="sc-bdVaJa fSbntV">
                            <div class="drop-down__menu">
                              <div class="drop-down__row">
                                <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                                <div class="drop-down__text">1. First Qtr </div>
                                <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                                <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="drop-down__row--disable">
                                <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                                <div class="drop-down__text">2. Second Qtr </div>
                                <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                                <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="drop-down__row">
                                <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
                                <div class="drop-down__text">3. Third Qtr </div>
                                <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
                                <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-down__row">
              <div class="drop-down__check"></div>
              <div class="drop-down__text">6. Live Chat</div>
              <span class="drop-down__hot-key"></span>
              <div class="drop-down__arrow--disable"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```